# How can I use the result array in my normalized state to render posts in sorted order

Tags: reactjs, normalizr

I have successfully used normalizr in my react app to normalize my API response. In my state, I have entities and the result array. I am using the entities to render posts in my react component but they are not in their original order.

I understand that the entities is an object, therefore it will not maintain the order. I also understand that i must use the result array since it has the ids in the original order. My questions is how do I go about using this result array in my react component to display the posts in their original order?

I have searched through the stack + google and I seem not to find a specific answer that addresses my question. I have also tried to do a sort before I map the entities object in my render as follows:

```
Object.values(posts).sort((a, b) => a.created_on > b.created_on)
```

or

```
Object.values(posts).sort((a, b) => a.created_on + b.created_on)
```

or

```
Object.values(posts).sort((a, b) => a.created_on - b.created_on)
```

and then using map. But all these do not work.

Is there a specific way to do this without using denormalizr?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot. However...

I just figured out that the sort method is not necessary in my render since I am using normalizr which **already** has a result array of all posts in the **correct** order by their IDs while obviously all posts data is in the entities object.

So I managed to map through that normalizr result array which holds all the key ids of every post and then return a new object with every post in the entities object sorted by its respective key id.

As this...

```
resultArray.map(post => postEntities[post]);
```

This gets all the posts in their correct order since I am mapping through the already ordered result array.

By the way, I am using selectors for this. So the code above is not in the render component but is in the selectors.js

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not calling the sort correctly? This seems to work:

```js
const sorter = (a, b) => {
  return a < b;
}

let posts = [4, 5, 7, 1]
posts.sort(sorter).map(i => console.log(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

We may need more info as I would believe that it should work. The following function sorts an array and renders it in increasing order inside of a react render return statement.

```
{array.sort((a, b) => a.created_on > b.created_on).map((item) => {
      return (
        <div>{item.name}</div>
      )
}}
```

By saying that it does not work, do you mean the posts render via a map but are not sorted? Posts do not render at all? I have not used normalizr but if normalizr is returning an array and you are performing a sort on the array, I would think the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Wes. Yes, the posts render via a map but are not sorted. Using the sort as you specified just weirdly rearranges the order, but not in the actual ordering as from the API. I believe the sort you mentioned truly should work but in this case it is not due to, I am guessing,  normalizr itself. So that could be the "somewhere else" you are referring to. I will dig a bit more. But if you figure something else, let me know. Thanks.